Question / Help with K Map and Circuit Diagram
I am currently working on a 7-Segment Hex Decoder and keep running into a issue with the decoder. I have tried many times to make a circuit based off the K-Map and table of values but ultimately fail at making sure each condition works properly. Based on the 4bit input into the decoder I want to determine which input corresponds to the first "A" segment on the display. But their is always at least one input that doesn't work.
[
I would include a picture of my own K-Map but it is very messy
The circuit that should theoretically work but doesn't for some reason
[

First off, I agree with the first 10 entries since they match up with the usual BCD mapping for the A segment of a 7-segment display. I accept the remainder, as given.
I think you got your logic entirely correct.
Just to be clear, here's the cleaned-up k-map that I produced using Neemann's Digital program:

Here's the resulting logic that the above-mentioned program automatically generates from it:

Although the auto-generated result didn't arrange the AND gates in the same vertical order, it matches nicely with your own result.
The table matches your resulting logic and I personally agree with your first 10 entries, as well, and can't disagree with the rest. So you must be mistaken about the output not accurately representing the table.

at least one input that doesn't work.

Can you point out which row, in your opinion, isn't producing the indicated Y output? How exactly are you testing this?

Thank you for your response and insight. Turns out you were correct. I made a tiny mistake with wiring my circuit which was causing the output to not be right.

@gauckin Glad I asked that last question. I was thinking you did everything perfectly. But I didn't know if you were writing in HDL for an FPGA or actually building something from logic ICs. Good to hear you got things working! (Oh. It may save others a little time spent wondering if you close the question by checking my answer. I don't care. So don't bother on my sake.)
